# getting the followers from a list of userID using twepy

Tags: list, tweepy, userid

userID = "@niveakalmar" <- I wanna have a list of users here and scrape all the followers of which one

user = api.get_user(userID)

for friend in user.friends():
print(friend.screen_name)

Answer (score 0):

followers and friends are different endpoints

this is the followers: you can adapt for freinds by changing followers to friends

```
def get_follower_list(num_followers, id):
    follower_list = []
    for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id).items(num_followers):
        follower_list.append(follower.screen_name)
    return follower_list

# get initial list of followers
num_followers = 5
user_list = ['GEODIS_Group']
for user_handle in user_list:
# print(user_handle)
    followers = get_follower_list(num_followers, user_handle)
print(followers)
```